# how to change the sequence of menu on the click in the windows 7

Tags: windows-7

when I double click on any text file it gives error Paint can not read this file ...
This is because the "EDIT" option is first in the list of click. How can I change the sequence so that "OPEN" menu will be first in the list and I can double click and open the text file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Tool called [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/), where you can edit the commands as shown in the picture.

[image]

You can also select which is the default action.

Comment: cool ... it's working